# Deciding whether there exists a permutation of the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix that is magic

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, matrices

Given an array of $n^2$ integers, what is the most efficient way to determine whether any permutation of those integers can form a magic square? "Magic square" being an arrangement of those integers on a square grid such that all rows, columns and diagonals sum to the same value.

Note that this isn't asking how to test if a given arrangement is a magic square, which would be $O(n^2)$, but whether any possible square formed from the array is magic.

Comment: Are you looking for a practical answer, or are you asking about the worst-case asymptotic complexity?  Are you more interested in the running time as a function of $n$ (treating the size of the integers as a constant), or the running time as a function of the size of the integers (treating $n$ as a constant), or do you really need to know the dependence on both parameters?  Related (but doesn't answer your question): https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3903/5038.

Comment: A practical answer would be nice, that runs in less than O(n!).

Comment: Add or subtract a constant so the smallest integer is 0. Obviously the sum of the integers must be divisible by $n^2$, and 2x the largest integer plus the 2n-2 smallest must not be greater than 2x the sum divided by n. Maybe there are other criteria showing quickly there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use integer linear programming, and hope that an ILP solver will be able to find a solution.  This will probably still be exponential in $n$ in the worst case, but it might be faster than enumerating all $n!$ solutions.

Here's more detail.  Suppose we are given the integers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n^2}$.  Let $M=(a_1+\dots+a_{n^2})/n$ be the [magic constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_constant) of the magic square, so that every row, every column, and every diagonal needs to sum to $M$.  Define zero-or-one integer variables $x_{i,j,k}$, with the intended meaning that $x_{i,j,k}=1$ means that the number $a_k$ is placed in row $i$, column $j$.  Then we have the inequalities

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_i a_k x_{i,j,k} = M\\
&\sum_j a_k x_{i,j,k} = M\\
&\sum_i a_k x_{i,i,k} = M\\
&\sum_i a_k x_{i,n+1-i,k} = M\\
&\sum_k x_{i,j,k} = 1\\
&\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,k} = 1.
\end{align*}$$

Then any feasible solution to these linear equalities will represent a valid magic square, so you can feed this to an off-the-shelf ILP solver and hope that it finds a solution for you.  Probably it will fail (take forever) once $n$ gets large, but it might be effective if $n$ is small enough.